# Vite stucks when trying to run dev

Tags: npm, vuejs3, vite, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run a project built on vuejs3 + vite and yarn.
This has always worked with the command "yarn dev" but when I run it now it hangs somewhere. Exactly where and why is difficult to find out.I dont get any error message. I do want to mention that I have executed the command "yarn dev" 10 times and 1 time the application did work without me having to do anything special.

I enabled --debug and unfortunately it didn't help me either.
Both the successful and the unsuccessful run look the same in terms of debug logs.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port 7777 --host 0.0.0.0 --force --debug",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.15.9",
    "apexcharts": "^3.37.2",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.28",
    "qrcode-vue3": "^1.4.17",
    "quasar": "^2.11.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-router": "4",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "vue3-tabs-chrome": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-chunk-split": "^0.4.7"
  }
}
```

I removed node_modules and installed it again but made no difference.

Are there other possibilities that could be causing this?

Comment: try to update your vite related modules (minor version) you have the old version. plus we need your vite.config.js. plus restart your pc you could have node.js processes / taken IP ports blocking your new vite process